# Como personalizar "Janela de confirmação"?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Segue o código:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", Confirm= "Tem certeza ?" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso personalizar um dialogo, tipo um modal bootstrap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é mais uma pergunta de JavaScript do que de ASP.NET MVC, mas vamos lá.

A ideia é ter isso no seu `<form>`:

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Tem certeza?');">
```

Ou seja:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", onsubmit="return confirm('Tem certeza?');" }))
{

}
```

[Veja mais sobre `Window.confirm()` aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm).